# Replacing AA battery source with LiPo

Tags: power-supply, batteries, charging, lipo, hacking

I have a brother label printer that usually runs on 9V DC source or 8x1.5V standard AA batteries. The DC input jack on brother died so I decided to replace it and try to upgrade it to Li-po battery source.

I have purchased 1350mAh 3.7V LiPo battery pack and hooked it to tc4056a based charger. On the input side I connected 5V source from DC jack for charging, and on output I put step up converter based on LM2577 which is tuned to 12V.

What happens now is that in standby mode the battery draw is 0.5A which is due to conversion I guess. When running the label printer it prints for a while until it shuts itself down (My guess is that the battery internal protection turns it off as I have to remove and insert battery to turn it back on)

Although while on charger and battery, the printer works just fine and the draw on LiPo battery is under 1A (It spikes to 1.2A and then gets down).

What could I do to make it fully working on LiPo battery? Should I put three batteries in series to get 11V and get rid of step up converter? How do I charge the batteries then?

Thanks in advance,
Leo.

Comment: What do you mean "input side"? Batteries don't have inputs. If you mean to charge these in-place at a location meant for AA batteries, then that sounds like a Very Bad Idea. Also what do you mean with "battery pack", is there a BMS, where is it, how does it work?

Comment: you could put three (or more) in parallel, that should get you longer run-time

Comment: I have ordered 3S BMS that I will use for charging 3 18650's in series. That should give me ~12V that I need along with good capacity. Will report back if it works.